# Python 3.5 is unable to access packages installed with pip3 like django

Tags: 16.04, python, python3, pip, django

I have both python 2.7 and python 3.5 installed on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I have also installed python3-pip to be used for installing external packages to python 3.5.

Using pip3 I have installed django using the following command:

```
sudo pip3 install django
```

This command installed the package into the dist-packages directory ar /usr/local/lib/python3.5 on my computer.

I have used similar commands for installing other packages as well.

However when I ran this command after to start a django server :

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

It show this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
   from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

Also when I start python3 onterminal and type:

```
import django
```

It too gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

I face similar problems with other python packages I have installed using pip3 like BeautifulSoup, xlrd, xlwt, youtube-dl. I can access none of them from python3.

I should also mention that I use Pycharm for Python development. In that, I can access all of these packages and it uses python3.5 as intepreter which is located at /usr/bin/.

My question is how do I solve?

I have tried using simply

```
pip3 install django
```

but that gives the following error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/rishav/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django'
```

I have googled this problem and I have not found any viable solution. Please help me resolve this problem.

Comment: What does `python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'` say?

Comment: It says : ['', '/usr/local/lib/python35.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/plat-linux', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/home/rishav/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages']

Answer (score 2):

Run the follwing:

1. as mentioned above, you need to apt-get install python-django or python3-django
2. sudo apt-get install python-pip (or sudo apt-get install python3-pip)
3. sudo apt-get install mysql-server (I would suggest you do not use sqlite3 if you want to work with databases) (THIS STEP IS OPTIONAL!!!!)
4. sudo apt-get install apache2 (for django to run on it)

Basic info:

1. Use django-admin startproject << name >>
2. Modify the django settings to run on the apache server
3. You must be inside the project location to be able to run << python manage.py runserver >>

Comment: I have apache2 installed but when I tried installing mod_wsgi for django to work with apache, the configure script could not find apxs or apxs2.

Comment: try this: 1. sudo apt-get install apache2-dev  2. restart the apache service

Comment: thank you it worked but during 'make' it threw this error:                   src/server/wsgi_python.h:24:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated. Sorry to bother you again

Comment: apt-get install python3-dev or python-dev, that should take care of it; let me know how it goes

Comment: It worked I could install mod_wsgi but I am having trouble configuring the httpd.conf file for apache2 to run django as I cannot find that file. I have checked at /usr/local/apache2/conf but there is no apache2 folder in usr/local. However when I go to 127.0.0.1 on my browser it shows the "It works!" page. So I am really baffled about my apache2 installation and running django on it.

Comment: 1. while in the directory of your newly created project, where manage.py  is located, run $ python manage.py runserver
2. go in the web browser, and type 127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: I don't have django installed for python2. So it doesn;t work. Also I seem to have two versions of django now on python3 -- 1.8.7 as well as 1.9.7. How can remove and then reinstall python3 on ubuntu so that I can restart python3?

Answer (score 1):

Well something must have went wrong during that pip3 install.
You can also Django like `sudo apt-get install python3-django`

Cheers [if this helps]